# Excel Filtering

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am trying to filter a list of MAC addresses based on another much smaller list. I saw a formula in another thread `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1;B:B;1;FALSE));"";A1)`, but I can't seem to get it to work for my purposes.

Basically, if I can get a conditional bit of text (like `matched` or `not matched` depending on if a MAC from my short list is found in the larger list) then I could filter based on `matched` or `not matched`.

Comment: Does changing the formula to `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1;B:B;1;FALSE));"Not matched";"Matched")` solve your problem?

Comment: I can't give the actual data due to the sensitivity of it, but I can give general information.

So, in my example I have a spreadsheet with switchports on 3 different switches. I have in my column I Phone MAC Address which will either be blank or will have a MAC address for a phone that is attached to that port. In column N I have pasted a list of MACs that I would like to filter off of. So I'd like to compare the small list with the larger list and specify if the MAC in column I matches or does not match a MAC in my short list (currently residing in Column N.

Comment: So based on Jerry's advice above I tried the following:
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,N2:N38,9,FALSE)),"Not Matched","Matched")

Comment: How should I change my array value? Does it need to be in the left-most column? I'd like to leave it as is because my system handles the certain columns a certain way.

Comment: ah, so change the array to N:N? and the offset to 1?

Comment: I changed it to `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,N2:N38,1,FALSE)),"Not Matched","Matched")` and I get all "Not Matched" when I do a Fill Down.

Comment: Oops, clicked the wrong link there. What does my formula need?

Comment: Ok, I added the dollar signs, but still getting "Not Matched"

Comment: Would this formula be case sensitive? I see my lookup array has upper case and my column i am trying to filter has the MAC addresses in lower case.

Comment: No `VLOOKUP` even with `false` at the end for exact match still will match regardless of case.  Remember the dollar signs should be for column N (i.e. $N$2:$N$38) and **not** for column I.  You want the row in I to change as you fill down but you dont want the lookup array to change

Comment: So, this is what I'll be using `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,$N$2:$N$38,1,FALSE)),"Not Matched","Matched")`

Comment: Still getting all "Not Matched" for the entire column.

Comment: That was it! Thanks pnuts! I think the file I had had spaces at the end

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,N$2:N$38,1,0)),"No Match","Match")` in row2 and copied down to suit should be sufficient, provided your long list starts in row2.

Comment: For filtering purposes I'd love for it to return a "Match" or "No Match"